# how to show data of databse in navigation bar on laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, navbar

i am new to laravel. currently  i am working on laravel 7. i made a navigation bar a seperate file which i extends on all the front end file.  i just  know that when i need a data from the database in front end
then i do like this

```
$cat = modelname::all();
        return view('addproducts')->with('cat',$cat);
```

but that code works on that condition when i have to go to that front end blade file. but  on navigation bar senario i dont need to go to the nav file i just go to another  blade file  and nav file is extended on it.
i just want to know how to access the data from the databse on navigation bar

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{'addcategory'}}">Add Catgory <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{'showcategory'}}">show Category</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Manage Products
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{'
                    addproducts'}}">Add Products</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

this is the code of my nav file where i want to get the data from the database and then  want to show in a dropdown menu

```
@extends('layouts.nav');
@section('content')
    //code for the front end of the page
    @endsection
```

this is how i extend the nav file on another page

Answer (score 0):

@Fahad Munir would something like this work in your case? Using 'include' instead of 'extends'?

```php
@include('layouts.nav', ['cat' => $cat = App\modelname::all();])
```

If this does not work for your purposes, you may also consider using a View Composer.

See the Laravel documentation about View Composers here:  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers.

Utilizing a View Composer would allow you to add something like the following to the `boot()` method in your `appServiceProvider` or after creating a new service provider using artisan and adding to the `boot()` method after doing that like so:

```php
view()->composer('layouts.nav', function($view) {
   $view->with('cat', App\modelname::all());
});
```

Read more about that in the Laravel documentation here, if need be:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/providers#the-boot-method

Comment: the composer is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

If your on Laravel 7 then you really need to use the new component feature added to Laravel 7, to do that run `php artisan make:component NavigationComponent`, this will generate a NavigationComponent class and a navigation-component blade file.

navigation-component.blade.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{'addcategory'}}">Add Catgory <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{'showcategory'}}">show Category</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Manage Products
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{'
                    addproducts'}}">Add Products</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

NavigationComponent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class NavigationComponent extends Component
{
    public $cat;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cat = CatModel::all();
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.navigation-component');
    }
}
```

For more visit [Laravel Component docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#components)

Comment: you don't **need** to use it ... you potentially could use it, but you don't **need** to use it

Comment: Its just my opinion, and i believe its definitely much better than mixin your view codes with business logic like so: `@include('layouts.nav', ['cat' => $cat = App\modelname::all();])`

Comment: @tsommie that was just one of the options I mentioned. Decent suggestion you got there though.